# How to find the point on a line closest to a set of n points in 2 space?

Tags: calculus, geometry

There are n points distributed in 2 space, with known coordinates. A straight line is drawn through the space.

How do I find the point on the line which minimizes the sum of the distances between itself and all other points?

Comment: How about a hint! - "Regression", rather starting from "Linear Regression", also you can use least square method!!, I hope that may be an idea?

Comment: A source - https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/least-squares-regression.html

Comment: This doesn't sound like regression to me.  The OP says that the line is given.

Comment: That's correct. The line is given, and I am trying to find a point on that given line.

Comment: You can parameterize the line with one parameter, and the the sum of the distances to the given points is a function of that parameter.  Then it's a minimization problem, but it's awfully messy -- you might have to solve it numerically.  It would be easy to minimize the sum of the *squares* of the distances.

Comment: I looked into minimizing the sum of the squares of the distances, but this only seemed to work for the case where n = 1. In all other cases, the distance takes the form d = sqrt(...) + ... + sqrt(...) which is not simplified by squaring both sides. Am I missing something?

Comment: You must be careful when you use the word "random". I suppose you are not looking for an answer which is a random variable, are you? In other words, we may assume that the $n$ points are given and their coordinates are known, right?

Comment: Yes, random was probably not the correct word to use. The n points are given and their coordinates known. The line is also given.

Comment: Thanks! And what do you mean by the "total distance"? The sum of distances between the point on the line and the other points?

Comment: Correct. The aim is to minimize the sum of the distances between the point on the line and each of the known points.

Comment: Ok. Just so you know, it is much easier to minimize the sum of the **squares** of the distances, rather than the sum of the distances themselves. In the former case it becomes a simple least-squares problem. saulpatz already remarked this above.

Comment: Is that possible for multiple points? The distance takes the form d = sqrt(...) + ... + sqrt(...) which is not simplified by squaring both sides. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

WLOG, the line is the axis $x$ (otherwise, translate/rotate).

You want to minimize

$$D(x):=\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{(x-x_k)^2+y_k^2}.$$

For this you need to solve

$$\frac{dD}{dx}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x-x_k}{\sqrt{(x-x_k)^2+y_k^2}}=0,$$

that has no closed-form solution (except for $n=2$). The terms in this sum are sigmoids, all growing from $-1$ to $1$, so that there is a single root.

You can try with Newton's iterations, from the initial approximation $x=\overline{x}_k$, which is in fact the value that minimizes the sum of the *squared* distances (by $\dfrac{dD}{dx}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n(x-x_k)=0$).

---

In the case of $n=1$, the solution is obviously $x=x_0$, i.e. you project the point orthogonally onto the line.

In the case of $n=2$,

$$\frac{x-x_0}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+y_0}}+\frac{x-x_1}{\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+y_1}}=0$$
can be transformed to the quadratic equation

$$(x-x_0)((x-x_1)^2+y_1^2)-(x-x_1)((x-x_0)^2+y_0^2)
\\=(x_0-x_1)x^2+(y_1^2-y_0^2+x_1^2-x_0^2)x+x_1y_0^2+x_1x_0^2-x_0y_1^2-x_0x_1^2=0.$$

But an alien root is introduced.

Geometrically, the solution is immediate: if the points are on opposite sides, intersect the line and the segment between the two points; otherwise reflect one of the points.

Comment: Maybe there’s a geometric solution as in the case of only two points.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: oh, yes of course: the straight line !

Comment: Not at all: you reflect one point on the straight line and connect this reflected point with the other one.  The intersection of those is the desired point.  This is well known, isn’t it

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: I mean, when the points are on opposite sides.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: thanks for developing the Newtonian expression. But isn't $x_n-\cdots$ missing ?

Comment: Take two: I deleted my answer because I realized the Newton iteration becomes $$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{x_n - x_k}{\sqrt{(x_n - x_k)^2 + y_k^2}}}{\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^N \frac{y_m^2}{\left((x_n - x_m)^2 + y_m^2\right)^{3/2}}}$$Thanks, Yves Daoust, for catching my stupid errors; even here I made a goof (thus take two; this is the corrected comment). I really don't want to lead others astray! :)